# How to make rpm spec that moves files that were previously marked as %config?

Tags: linux, centos, rpm, rpm-spec

The problem I'm trying to solve is following:

In older releases of my package there were config files placed at `/srv/product/` dir.

```
%config /srv/product/conf1
%config /srv/product/conf2
```

But in next upcoming release I removed these conf files from the package.
In case if user upgrades the package with new version (where configs are no longer included into rpm) I want configs from previous release to be moved to different dir (which is part of pkg) and keep them there, but still to have them as not part of package.

I tried to move files with `%pre` and `%post` scriplets but it didn't work. The old configs are either moved and then overwritten by their parent dir or are already been removed at `/srv/product`.

Is it possible to implement that within rpm spec file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to save the file in %pre and restore it in %post section.
How you can save the file or in general any state see
https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:ScriptletSnippets#Saving_state_between_scriptlets

Comment: %posttrans and %pretrans did the job in my specific case. Thank you.